# R : Text Analysis - tm Package - stemComplete error

Tags: regex, r, text, tm, stemming

Machine: Windows 7 - 64 bit
R Version : R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"

I am working on stemming some text for an analysis that I am doing, I am able to do everything all the way up until 'stemComplete'  For more context please see the below;

Packages:

1. TM
2. SnowballC
3. rJava
4. RWeka
5. Rwekajars
6. NLP

## Sample list of words

```
test <- as.vector(c('win', 'winner', 'wins', 'wins', 'winning'))
```

## Convert to Corpus

```
Test_Corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(test))
```

## Text manipulations`

```
Test_Corpus <- tm_map(Survey_Corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
Test_Corpus <- tm_map(Survey_Corpus, removePunctuation)
Test_Corpus <- tm_map(Survey_Corpus, removeNumbers)
```

## Stemming using tm_map under the tm package

```
>Test_stem <- tm_map(Test_Corpus, stemDocument, language = 'english' )
```

## Below is the result from stemming above, which is all correct so far:

1. win
2. winner
3. win
4. win
5. win

## Now comes the issue! When I try to use test_corpus as a dictionary to transform the words back to an appropriate format using the following code;

```
>Test_complete <- tm_map(Test_stem, stemCompletion, Test_Corpus)
```

## Below is the error message that I am getting:

## Warning messages:

```
1: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be  used
2: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) :
argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have tried several things listed on previous posts and seen that other people with the same problem have tried with no luck.  Below is a list of those things:

1. Update Java
2. used content_transformation
3. used PlainTextDocument

Comment: I'm not sure your formatting is doing what you think it is. Indent for code blocks (including comments) and try to avoid overuse of headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save your test_corpus as a dictionary before the stemming process. You could try something like `Test_Corpus <- corpus` then you could start the steming and using corpus later on in `Test_complete <- tm_map(corpus, stemCompletion)`.

Comment: By changing the name of the corpus at the point of stemming it does the same things right?